# F# algorithm for hk

Tags: f#

Can anyone help me with this problem?

"Realize a function which duplicate each item in a list. You can use List.map"
IN F# sharp language.

And also

"Use the List.init function to generate a list of n random natural numbers between 0 and m."

```
let makeCopy elem Count =
    match Count with 
    | 0 -> []
    | 1 -> elem

let rec dupeElem row count =
    match row with
    | [] -> []
    | hd::tl -> (makeCopy hd count) @ dupeElem tl count


    //let xs = [1; 2; 3]
    //xs |> List.collect (fun x -> List.replicate 3 x)
    //val it : int list = [1; 1; 2; 2; 3; 3]
```

Comment: In what part do you need help exactly? Can you show anything you have tried, even if it's not working correctly?

Comment: These are two different questions.

Comment: Homework? What is "hk"? We can help, but as @Pac0 already said, we'd love to help, but show us where you got stuck.Welcome to SO, you may want to have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm a beginner  in F#, it's my first day and i had already some troubles.

Comment: @abel now i think it's ok

Comment: I made it compilable. Order of declarations is important. However, I noticed you already have the solution, it's hidden in the comments, with `Array.replicate` and `Array.collect`

Answer (score 1):

Duplicating the items is pretty straight forward, you just need a recursive function that walks the list.

Generating the random numbers is where you can use `List.init` to create a new list. You can use the .NET `Random` class to generate the random  numbers you're after.

This gives up the following functions:

```
let rec duplicateItems list =
    match list with
    | [] -> []
    | head :: tail -> head :: head :: duplicateItems tail

let makeRandomList count upperBound =
    let random = Random()
    List.init count (fun i -> random.Next(0, upperBound))
```

You can now generate a random list and pipe it into the duplicate function:

```
let numbers = makeRandomList 10 20 |> duplicateItems
```

NOTE: `duplicateItems` is not tail recursive, so for really large lists this might be an issue. You can get around this by treating the data to duplicate as a sequence:

```
let duplicateSequence sequence =
    seq {
        for a in sequence do
            yield a
            yield a
    }
```

Now we just need to pipe the result into `Seq.toList`:

```
let numbers = makeRandomList 10 20 |> duplicateSequence |> Seq.toList
```

We could also have written `makeRandom` to return a sequence rather than a list. This would have made the whole computation lazy up until the point we call `Seq.toList`.

Answer (score 0):

> *which duplicate each item in a list. You can use List.map*

I think your own solution with `List.collect` is fine. But here's one with `List.map`:

```
> let dupe x = List.map (fun s -> [s;s]) x |> List.concat
val dupe : x:'a list -> 'a list
> dupe [1;2;3];;
val it : int list = [1; 1; 2; 2; 3; 3]
```

> *Use the List.init function to generate a list of n random natural numbers between 0 and m*

I'll show you the general idea, then you can work out the rest, I'm sure. This basically works:

```
> let rand n max = let r = Random() in List.init n (fun _ -> r.Next(0, max));;
val rand : n:int -> max:int -> int list

> rand 10 12;;
val it : int list = [11; 11; 10; 11; 6; 1; 3; 6; 8; 2]
```